# Inverting filter and joining two filters in vim

Tags: vim, text-editor

I am trying to filter a file in gvim using some keywords.
The :v command serves the purpose.
I do `:v/bread/d` and I have only the lines containing the word *bread*. 
Now, I want to invert the filter to show me only the lines which DO NOT contain the word *bread*. Can someone please help me with this?
And while we are at it, how can we use multiple filters in one go?
Right now, I can do `:v/butter/d` after the previous :v to find only the lines containing both *bread*(result from previous :v) and *butter*(result from this :v). But, I would like to combine both bread and butter in one command and possibly, be also able to invert the combination(to show all lines NOT containing *bread* and *butter*)

Comment: I cannot understand your exact requirement. can you make some examples? like, before .... after....

Answer (score 4):

> show me only the lines which DO NOT contain the word *bread*

In your own terms: globally delete lines that contain *bread*:

```
:g/bread/d
```

> combine both *bread* and *butter* in one command

Remove lines containing neither *bread* nor *butter*:

```
:g!/^.*bread.*$\&^.*butter.*$/d
```

> invert the combination(to show all lines NOT containing *bread* and *butter*)

Remove lines containing both *bread* and *butter*:

```
:g/^.*bread.*$\&^.*butter.*$/d
```

PS. I prefer to write `:g!` instead of `:v` but I think these commands are equivalent.

Comment: They are equivallent. fwiw, I tend to use the blackhole register `d_` to speed up deleting lines. I don't remember what option it is in my .vimrc but without using the blackhole register, each deleted line got copied to my clipboard slowing things down considerabely.

Comment: You can create these patterns via `:LogiPat` which has been recently shipped with Vim. `:LogiPat "bread" & "butter"` then do `:v//d_` to remove any line that containing neither bread nor butter. See `:h :LogiPat`.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to combine both bread and butter in one command and possibly, be also able to invert the combination (*to show all lines NOT containing bread AND butter*)

To show all lines NOT containing bread AND butter:

```
g/bread.*butter\|butter.*bread/d
```

Other possible combinations are:

- To delete all lines containing bread OR butter:

  ```
  :g/bread\|butter/d
  ```
- To delete all lines NOT containing bread OR butter:

  ```
  :v/bread\|butter/d
  ```